# Conversion failure. Could not find Chromium binaries (trying to load from *[Project]\Chromium\)

Tags: chromium, blink, selectpdf

I'm trying to use Blink as rendering engine but it fails. Installed Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore.Blink and using .net v4.8.

I have a single file "Select.Html.dep" inside bin folder. Running with iisexpress.

```
// instantiate a html to pdf converter object
var converter = new HtmlToPdf()
{
    Options = {
        RenderingEngine = RenderingEngine.Blink,
        PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4,
        PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait,
        MarginTop = 20,
        MarginRight = 20,
        MarginBottom = 20,
        MarginLeft = 20,

        DisplayFooter = true
    }
};

// create a new pdf document converting an url
var doc = converter.ConvertUrl(url);

// save pdf document
byte[] response = doc.Save();

// close pdf document
doc.Close();
```

Comment: See where the package manager installed the package and either copy the Chromium folder to your bin folder or point to that folder using BlinkEnginePath property of converter.Options.

Comment: I thought this was done automatically. Thank you.